# How to fallback to $HOME if Tramp failed to connect to default-directory

Tags: tramp, find-file, ido-find-file

If I call `find-file` from a buffer with `default-directory` pointing to a remote server via TRAMP and the remote server is not reachable, then TRAMP complains:

> tramp-signal-hook-function: Tramp failed to connect.  If this happens
> repeatedly, try
> ‘M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection’

It took me a while to understand that I either need to call `find-file` from a different buffer or change `default-directory` (e.g. with the `cd` command). Otherwise I can't open any file.

Is there a way to either tell find-file to fallback to my $HOME in case of this specific TRAMP error or to tell find-file from the start to ignore the default-directory and to start with $HOME?

I can imagine to use e.g. the [prefix argument](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrefixArgument) for this behavior. Currently there does not seem to be any behavior defined for the prefix argument to find-file.

I use IDO for find-file but am open to switch to something else.

Comment: You do *NOT* want to have `find-file` start with `$HOME` always - trust me on that: it will drive you crazy.

Comment: Why not follow the directions in the message and do `M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection`? That way, it will not bother you again.